# Google Calendar API Token not refreshing

Tags: php, google-api, google-oauth, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

For some reason when my token expires I need to delete the file and reconnect again otherwise nothing is working. Is it because the new token is not stored or?

I have the following code:

```
if(!$_GET['id']){
            echo print_r('BUSINESS NOT FOUND');
            exit();
        }else {

            $client = new Google_Client();
            $client->setApplicationName('Google Calendar API PHP Quickstart');
            $client->setScopes(Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR);
            $client->setAuthConfig(__DIR__ . '/client.json');
            $client->setAccessType('offline');
            $client->setPrompt('select_account consent');


            // Load previously authorized token from a file, if it exists.
            // The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
            // created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
            // time.
            $tokenPath = '../Remindly/accounts/' . $_GET['id'] . '.json';
            if (file_exists($tokenPath)) {
                $accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents($tokenPath), true);
                $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
                return $client;
            }

            // If there is no previous token or it's expired.
            if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
                // Refresh the token if possible, else fetch a new one.
                if ($client->getRefreshToken()) {
                    $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
                }
                // Save the token to a file.
                file_put_contents($tokenPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
            }

        }
```

Comment: Define nothing works do you have an error mesage?

Comment: @DalmTo - I can't extract any data from the calendar. I need to delete the file when the token is stored and connect again in order for the whole thing to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### It seems that you are not returning `client` in case the token expired

Modify your code as shown in the [quickstart for PHP](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/php) to return the client at the end of the function - both if the access token expired and if it did not:

```php
...
if(...){
...
}else{
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName('Google Calendar API PHP Quickstart');
    $client->setScopes(Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR_READONLY);
    $client->setAuthConfig('credentials.json');
    $client->setAccessType('offline');
    $client->setPrompt('select_account consent');

    // Load previously authorized token from a file, if it exists.
    // The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    // created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    // time.
    $tokenPath = 'token.json';
    if (file_exists($tokenPath)) {
        $accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents($tokenPath), true);
        $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
    }

    // If there is no previous token or it's expired.
    if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        // Refresh the token if possible, else fetch a new one.
        if ($client->getRefreshToken()) {
            $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
        } else {
            // Request authorization from the user.
            $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
            printf("Open the following link in your browser:\n%s\n", $authUrl);
            print 'Enter verification code: ';
            $authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));

            // Exchange authorization code for an access token.
            $accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authCode);
            $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

            // Check to see if there was an error.
            if (array_key_exists('error', $accessToken)) {
                throw new Exception(join(', ', $accessToken));
            }
        }
        // Save the token to a file.
        if (!file_exists(dirname($tokenPath))) {
            mkdir(dirname($tokenPath), 0700, true);
        }
        file_put_contents($tokenPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
    }
    return $client;
}
...
```